# Call onStart() of Fragment before to display Viewpager, navigation_mode_tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-viewpager

I used a ViewPager and an ActionBar with NavigationMode : "NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS"

I put 3 Fragments : Fragment0 (left tab) ,Fragment1 (middle tab),Fragment2(right tab)

First, the Fragment0 appears and the methods "onCreateView" and "onStart" are called for Fragment0 AND the Fragment1

If I slide horizontally to go to the "middle tab"(Fragment1), the methods "onCreateView" and "onStart" of Fragment2(right tab) are called...

So, I want to know if this is normal ?

Because I want to call "onStart" of Fragment2 just before it appears, How do it?

My code :

```
public class ActivityPrincipale extends FragmentActivity {
    private Intent intentService1;   
    private Fragment fragment;
    [..]
    private ActionBar.TabListener tabListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
        super.onCreate(arg0);        
        setContentView(R.layout.viewpager);
        // Création de la liste de Fragments que fera défiler le PagerAdapter
        listFragments = new Vector();

        // Ajout des Fragments dans la liste des fragments
         listFragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Fragment0.class.getName()));
         listFragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Fragment1.class.getName()));
         listFragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Fragment2.class.getName()));

        // Création de l'adapter qui s'occupera de l'affichage de la liste de Fragments
        this.mPagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), listFragments);

        pagerView = (ViewPager) super.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        // affectation de l'adapter au ViewPager
        pagerView.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);

        pagerView.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // Quand il y a un swapp entre les page
                // on selectionne le tab correspondant
                Log.w("SWAPPING FRAGMENT!!", "swapping de fragment avec comme positin de destination = " + position);
                getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(position); // DEBUGMODE

            }
        });

        actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Create a tab listener that is called when the user changes tabs.
        tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {

            public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {             
                pagerView.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }
            public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {               
            }
            public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {                
            }
        };

        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Frag0").setTabListener(tabListener));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Frag1"").setTabListener(tabListener));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Frag2").setTabListener(tabListener));
    }
}
```

One Fragment :

```
public class Fragment0 extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_0, container, false);
        Log.w("oFragmento", "fragment0");
        return rootView;

    }

}
```

My PagerAdapter :

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final List fragments; 

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List list_fragments) {
        super(fm);       
        this.fragments = list_fragments;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {           
        return (Fragment) fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {        
        return this.fragments.size();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is completely normal for a Fragment to go through `onCreateView` then `onStart`. You may want to take a look at the [Fragment Lifecycle.](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating)

If I understand you correctly when you say "just before it appears", then I think the lifecycle method you are looking for is the `onResume` method. This is the last one to be called before the fragment is active.

Comment: Thus the offset is normal, but how can I force the call at "onStart" or "onCreateView" or "onResume" juste before it appears (or at the time of the appearance) ? 

because I using an ListView within Fragment1  when I chose an item, the Fragment2 is displayed but  his "onStart"/"onCreateView"/"onResume" its not called... I would like to update

Comment: Those are lifecycle events for the fragment. The start up events are called everytime, some of the ending lifecycle events may not be called due to memory being reclaimed by the OS.